# Microsoft Teams auto-reply to specific user

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm looking for a way to do this in Teams:

- Invoke some logic when a private chat (not a channel message) is received for me
- Look at the sender and the text of the message
- Based on the above, send a specific reply

I've built Microsoft bot framework chatbots before and connected them to a Teams channel, but I'm not sure if this is possible for incoming private chat messages.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: API does not support 1:1 messaging.

Comment: I am also looking for this functionality, but based on my research, it does not seem like it is possible.